# Expressing integrals as limits

Tags: calculus

> Express the definite integral as a limit of right-end point Riemann sums.
>   $$\int_{a}^{b}\! e^{u^2} \,\mathrm du$$

This is my answer. I was wondering if it is correct:

\begin{gather*}
\Delta{u_i}=\frac{b-a}{n}\\
c_i=a+\frac{b-a}{n}i
\end{gather*}

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{b-a}{n}e^{\left(a+\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)i\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

This looks right,
though I was initially confused by you writing
"$/c_i = ...$" -
I thought the "/" was a division,
not a separator.
It might have been better 
to put them on separate lines
or use a comma or semicolon as the separator.

If you wanted to use midpoints
instead of endpoints,
you could write
$c_i=a+\dfrac{b-a}{n}(i-1/2)$
or
$c_i=a+\dfrac{b-a}{2n}(2i-1)$
so that the formula is

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{b-a}{n}e^{(a+(b-a)(i-1/2)/n)^2}$$